# How to test BroadcastReceiver's setResultData() with Robolectric

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, robolectric

My `BroadcastReceiver` receives `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`.  It needs to call `this.setResultData(null)` so that the number is not subsequently dialled, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL).

This works fine.

How can I test this with Robolectric?

This is what I have:

```
// Create the intent
Intent myIntent = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, "123");

// Find my BroadcastReceiver
List<BroadcastReceiver> receivers = ShadowApplication.getInstance().getReceiversForIntent(myIntent);
MyReceiver receiver = (MyReceiver)receivers.get(0);

// Invoke it - I understand this is the correct way to do it in a Robolectric test
Context context = ShadowApplication.geInstance().getApplicationContext();
receiver.onReceive(context, myIntent);
```

My Broadcast receiver is launched, but when it calls `setResultData()` an exception is raised: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call while result is not pending`.  This happens due to the state of the underlying `BroadcastReceiver` because `setResultData()`->`checkSynchronousHint()` finds that `mPendingResult==null`.

`mPendingResult` is only ever set non-null by `setPendingResult()`, which I cannot call (even using reflection).

What is the proper way to test `BroadcastReceiver` which needs to call `setResultData()` please?

Comment: Can you do not call `onReceive()` manually, but fire the intent in the same way as you fire it in the application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried calling `context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent,null)` - but I get the same result: exception on setResultData().

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Nirali I'm afraid I don't remember, and I currently don't have access to the code for that project to check.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your issue and was not able.

Take a look to my test https://github.com/emartynov/robolectic-experiments/blob/master/robolectric-3.0-test/src/test/java/com/bijdorpstudio/myapplication/IncomingCallReceiverTest.java

However, I was not able to get `BroadcastReceiver` to be picked up by Robolectric from **AndroidManifest.xml**. Added by hand in tests.

And  I think it is OK approach. I would add some xml test for correct `BroadcastReceiver` tagging in **AndroidManifest.xml**. Testing that android is correctly picking it up will be still my lowest priority task

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My receiver is picked up fine from the manifest - but still raises an exception when it calls setResultData() :-(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I agree that setting up the filter in the manifest is not so important.  I'm baffled why your example works (i.e. you can call setResultData) and mine doesn't.  I can't see any relevant differences - but evidently there must be one.

Comment: I send broadcast first before getting result. This one difference that I see